# Clarify that the tag-wiki excerpt is plaintext, and don't pretend otherwise

Tags: feature-request, design, markdown, revision-history, tag-excerpt

As many visitors on meta have probably painfully learned from painful experience, tag-excerpts are plain-text.

Not that the editing-help or anything else hints at that:

> The **usage guidance, or tag wiki excerpt**, is a short blurb that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.

I suggest inserting *plaintext* between *short* and *blurb*. It would probably also be useful to emphasize it, by using italic.

Still, that isn't even the worst offender:
If you do look at the revision-history, the site pretends markdown is available for them:

[image: tag-excerpt history rendering it as markdown]

That should obviously be changed to handle excerpts as plaintext.